# unable to send post request properly in laravel 5.1

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, laravel-5.1

I am sending the post request in ajax like

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'test',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { id: sessionStorage.getItem('user_id') },
        dataType: 'JSON',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"/*,
        success:function(id){
        alert(sessionStorage.getItem('user_id'));
    }*/
    });
```

and my route is

```
Route::post('test','FacebookControllers\MessageController@getUserMessages');
if($request->has('id'))
        {
            echo "yahoo";
        }
```

which does not print the string, it means request is not being sent or the variable.

Comment: Do you receive any error in your console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove `contentType` from ajax request and it worked for me.

Comment: The reason for this is because jQuery is expecting a JSON response back from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting json data, so you have to return the response like that:

```
Route::post('test','FacebookControllers\MessageController@getUserMessages');
if($request->has('id')){
    return response()->json(['id' => 'yahoo']);
}
else{
    return response()->json(['id' => 'does not exist'])
}
```

Now print the result at console in order to verify it:

```
console.log('id before ajax: ' + sessionStorage.getItem('user_id'));
$.ajax({
    url: 'test',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { id: sessionStorage.getItem('user_id') },
    dataType: 'JSON',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    success:function(data){
        console.log('id after ajax: ' + data.id);
    }
});
```

Comment: I am only getting `id before ajax` value. One thing I want to pointout that below my scripts I am adding `$(function () {

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('value')
            }
        });
    });` and if I change `value` to `content` according the official docs then I get `500 internal server error while sending the request`.